# getting "java.io.IOException: error=24, Too many open files" when I try to run BigBlueButton

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bigbluebutton

I've installed a clean BigBlueButton on Ubuntu server but when I try to run it I can't and when I tried to debug I got this error.

```
java.io.IOException: error=24, Too many open files

Mar 12 05:35:11 NC-PH-2486 run-prod.sh[27006]: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing LimitNOFILE=8024 from 1024 in /lib/systemd/system/bbb-web.service and then "sudo systemctl restart bbb-web".

Also note that BigBlueButton won't scale to use all of those cores.

Ref:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/bigbluebutton-setup/LimitNOFILE|sort:date/bigbluebutton-setup/NkIt3Dq4HhY/nE0d31uoDgAJ